# Al hacer npm install, se me borran cosas en el package lock que a otros compañeros no les pasa

Tags: nodejs, npm

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como sucede en la imagen, al hacer un npm install se me borran todas esas lineas de código y en muchos otros paquetes que tienen devOptional se lo reemplaza por dev automaticamente, alguno sabe la razón?

Comment: Intenta copiando el contenido de la carpeta front a otra carpeta nueva, no copies la carpeta completa ya que se te puede colar una configuración oculta, tampoco copies node_modules, package.json ni package-lock.json. Una vez hecho eso instala nuevamente tus dependencias y revisa si funciona.

Comment: Lo que `npm install` hace es crear otro archivo package-lock.json, prueba utilizando `npm ci` o `npm i`. [Documentación de `npm ci`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-ci?v=true)